# How can I use conda to install pydot?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, pydot

Trying to generate some PDF's of decision trees by following [some of the sklearn documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/tree.html#classification), but can't get Pydot on my machine.  Is there any way to use the conda installer to install the pydot package?  Based on the command line errors I'm seeing, it may be a 64bit issue. I use binstar search to find the package channel:

```
C:\binstar search -t conda
```

Which gives the recommendation of looking at the packages in detail using

```
binstar show j14r/pydot
```

Which then tells me to

```
conda install --channel https://conda.binstar.org/j14r pydot
```

But when I run the conda install command, I get the following error (same error for all the pydot packages listed):

```
Fetching package metadata: ...
Error: No Packages found in current win-64 channels matching: pydot
You can search for this package with 

binstar search t conda pydot
```

which sends me back to the beginning of this all.  Any ideas?  Thanks all.

Comment: did `conda install -y pydot` not work? What about `conda install -y pydot -c conda-forge`?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This may help for someone who is looking for For Anaconda on Windows 10 64 Bit,
Environment: Windows 10 64 Bit, Python 3.5.2, Anaconda 4.2.0 (64-bit)

1. Download "graphviz-2.38.msi" from https://graphviz.gitlab.io/_pages/Download/Download_windows.html
2. Execute the "graphviz-2.38.msi" file
3. Add the graphviz bin folder to the PATH system environment variable (Example: "C:\Graphviz2.38\bin")
4. Go to Anaconda Prompt using start menu (Make sure to right click and select "Run as Administrator". We may get permission issues if Prompt as not opened as Administrator)
5. Execute the command: conda install graphviz
6. Execute the command: pip install git+https://github.com/nlhepler/pydot.git
7. Execute the command "conda list" and make sure pydot and graphviz modules are listed.
   Thanks

Comment: You can use `import pydot;
print pydot.find_graphviz()` to check if you missed a step

Comment: I get this error at step 6 :

https://github.com/nlhepler/pydot.git C:\temps\pip-req-build-v85u4f9_
Cannot find command 'git' - do you have 'git' installed and in your PATH?

Comment: Yes, we need to have Git installed and available in PATH. Make sure git is available by executing "git --version"

Comment: I did all the steps except one difference: I was activating a conda environment  and I was doing it in that environment. It didn't work. Then I switched to base environment and did the steps and it worked.

Answer (score 12):

I had the same question for my Anaconda3 x64 installation on Windows 8.1.

Here is what I did:

1) Installed Github for Windows https://windows.github.com/

2) Opened the Git Shell (which is a PowerShell session that allows git commands)

3) Install the pydot from https://github.com/nlhepler/pydot with this command:

```
./pip install git+https://github.com/nlhepler/pydot.git
```

4) You can check whether pydot was installed by issuing

```
conda list
```

Answer (score 4):

New **pydot** link for 64-bit installer https://anaconda.org/rmg/pydot or just

`conda install -c rmg pydot`

Answer (score 3):

Try running the following:

```
conda install -c https://conda.binstar.org/sstromberg pydot
```

Answer (score 3):

Most of the people gave great insights, here's a procedure which I find useful for myself -

assumed conf. -> Anaconda 4.4.0 or higher, Win 8+, and using anaconda prompt

- Few required installations (no order necessary)

  1. `pip install pydot-ng`
  2. `conda install graphviz`
  3. `pip install graphviz`
- PATH setting -> Under user environment variables add `C:/Anaconda/Library/bin/graphviz` in PATH (not Path)
- Go to `C:/Anaconda/Lib/site-packages/keras/utils/`
  Now open `vis_utils.py` in an editor and change line 11 from `import pydot` to `import pydot_ng as pydot`
- All set, now go to Jupyter notebook and type following commands -
  `import graphviz`
  `import pydot_ng as pydot`
  `pydot.find_graphviz()`
  If everything went well then you will find something similar to as shown below -
  `{'circo': 'C:\\Anaconda\\Library\\bin\\graphviz\\circo.exe',`
   `'dot': 'C:\\Anaconda\\Library\\bin\\graphviz\\dot.exe',`
  `'fdp': 'C:\\Anaconda\\Library\\bin\\graphviz\\fdp.exe',`
  `'neato': 'C:\\Anaconda\\Library\\bin\\graphviz\\neato.exe',`
  `'sfdp': 'C:\\Anaconda\\Library\\bin\\graphviz\\sfdp.exe',`
  `'twopi': 'C:\\Anaconda\\Library\\bin\\graphviz\\twopi.exe'}`

Answer (score 1):

Try this (from Anaconda Prompt):

```
conda install pydot-ng
```

Then, in your code:

```
try:
    import pydot_ng as pydot
except ImportError:
    import pydot # if someone running with old installation
```

More about [Pydot-ng](https://github.com/pydot/pydot-ng)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the j14r pydot package is built for 32-bit Windows, but I'm guessing you are using the 64-bit conda. See https://conda.binstar.org/j14r.

Comment: Yup, exactly.  I feel silly for asking, but can you point me to how I can build it for 64-bit?  Or, at least install it using the Conda installer?

Answer (score 0):

For me:

```
conda install -y pydot
```

worked. If not try:

```
conda install -y pydot -c conda-forge
```

I'm surprised I didn't have to do `conda install -y graphviz` however.