# Installing pydot and graphviz packages in Anaconda environment

Tags: python, graphviz, anaconda, pydot

I want to be able to create graphical decision trees in Python, and I am currently trying to install both `pydot` and `graphviz`.

I am using Anaconda as my environment (along with Spyder), and have tried to run the following lines of code

```
conda install -c https://conda.binstar.org/t/TOKEN/j14r pydot
```

with the result

```
Error: unknown host: http://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/win-32/
Error: unknown host: http://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/win-32/
Error: unknown host: https://conda.binstar.org/t/TOKEN/j14r/win-32/
Error: No packages found matching: pydot
```

I have also tried using `pip install pydot` and `pip install graphviz` with similar results:

```
Downloading/unpacking pydot
  Cannot fetch index base URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement pydot
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for pydot
Storing complete log in [...]
```

I am getting pretty bored at trying to figure out how to go about this, so I was hoping anyone out there could give me some tips perhaps.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you can open those links in the browser?

Comment: Also, have you tried with `--allow-external`?

Comment: What do you mean? Indeed, it seems the TOKEN one is weird, but the others are ok.

Comment: No, i have not tried that. What would be the correct full string?

Comment: `pip install --allow-external pydot`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66907/discussion-between-gussilago-and-lawrence).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I use conda to install pydot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26349314/how-can-i-use-conda-to-install-pydot)

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue and solved it by (order is **important**):

1. Installing `graphviz`, simply via `sudo apt-get install graphviz`
2. Installing `graphviz` for Python via conda `sudo ~/anaconda2/bin/conda install graphviz`
3. Finally, by installing `pydot` using conda `sudo ~/anaconda2/bin/conda install pydot`

This answer is overdue but this post helped me (together with [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18438997/why-is-pydot-unable-to-find-graphvizs-executables-in-windows-8) that mentions the installation order), so hopefully this answer will help someone else. I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 and Python 2.7.

P.S. apparently, there could be some issues with step 1 of the above algorithm, [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/196230/how-do-i-install-graphviz-2-29-in-12-04) mentions how to fix them.

Answer (score 3):

**the problem is solved for me by installing**

1. pydot         `conda install -c anaconda pydot`
2. graphviz     `conda install -c conda-forge python-graphviz`

Answer (score 2):

```
pip install pydotplus
conda install -c anaconda graphviz=2.38.0
```

(see here for latest versions https://anaconda.org/anaconda/graphviz)

worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

`pip install pydot` should now install version 1.2.3 from [PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/pydot/#files). Since the time of the OP, a distribution for `pydot` has been uploaded to PyPI.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Just Installed it]
Please see if this works for you...

1) Open the "Anaconda Prompt" by simply pressing WINDOW + S (for Windows OS Users) and type CMD. Then Select accordingly.

2) Type the command "***pip install pydot***"

3) Follow the onscreen information.

NOTE: I'm using Conda version 4.3.21 and Python 3.6

And Decision Tree Implementation below:

[Graphical Visualization of the Decision Tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VaabB.png)

Comment: Please use a comment if you're not sure. You can comment instead of answering after getting enough reputation. Yes, I know it's a bit of moment 22. :)

Answer (score 0):

installing graphviz first and then installing pydotplus on mac, helped me. I was not able to install pydot through pip or conda or even through jupiter notebook.
after installing, imported pydotplus(instead of usual pydot)

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "after installing, imported pydotplus(instead of usual pydot)"?