# Installing Pydot and Graphviz in Anaconda environment with Python 3 (MacOS)

Tags: python, anaconda, graphviz, pydot

I would like to install pydot and graphviz in my Python 3 Anaconda distribution, however, conda complains about a conflict between pydot and Python 3 :

```
UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - pydot -> pyparsing 1.5.6 -> python 2.7*
  - python 3.5*
Use "conda info <package>" to see the dependencies for each package.
```

I am on MacOS El Capitan.

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27482170/installing-pydot-and-graphviz-packages-in-anaconda-environment) but it didn't help much since when I try to install Graphviz from their website they don't have any version for El Capitan.. So I can't even do step 1.

Any help would be appreciated (changing distribution is not an option..) !

Answer (score 0):

GraphViz can be installed on El Capitan via [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org), as discussed [here](http://www.graphviz.org/Download_macos.php). After installing MacPorts itself, run:

```sh
port install graphviz
```

The GraphViz-related ports are listed [here](https://ports.macports.org/search/?q=graphviz&name=on). `pydot` can be installed [from PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/pydot/):

```sh
pip install pydot
```

The dependency of `pyparsing` that you see is an old version, which means that you are trying to install an old version of `pydot`. The latest `pydot == 1.2.3` is available on PyPI.

Comment: Unfortunately MacPorts is in conflict with Anaconda,  I've had seriously annoying problems when using both together ! Is there any solution that works without MacPorts ?

Comment: There is a `*.pkg` on GraphViz's website, or building GraphViz from [source](https://github.com/ellson/MOTHBALLED-graphviz). Regarding Python, I've never used Anaconda, and in my indirect experience it only causes problems (flat is better than nested [[PEP 20](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)]). I used to use MacPorts, until I realized that is nested too. The simplest solution that always works is to build CPython from its [source](https://github.com/python/cpython), which is what I do. On MacOS, just make sure to use the default system compiler, and install OpenSSH from source.