# Cannot install pydot package for Anaconda 3

Tags: anaconda, pydot

Tried installing pydot using the command

```
conda install -c anaconda pydot
```

and then

```
conda install -c anaconda pydot=1.2.3
```

Got the below error both times

```
PackageNotFoundError: Packages missing in current channels:
```

- pydot 1.2.3*

We have searched for the packages in the following channels:

- https://conda.anaconda.org/anaconda/win-64
- https://conda.anaconda.org/anaconda/noarch
- https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/win-64
- https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/noarch
- https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/win-64
- https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/noarch
- https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/win-64
- https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/noarch
  ........

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I use conda to install pydot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26349314/how-can-i-use-conda-to-install-pydot)