# keras plot_model tells me to install pydot

Tags: windows, python-3.x, keras, graphviz, pydot

I'm using python 3.6.3 on a windows 10 machine. I installed pydot and graphviz using pip install via:

```
    py -m pip install pydot
    py -m pip install graphviz
```

I also went to the graphviz website and downloaded and installed the windows version here: http://www.graphviz.org/Download_windows.php which default installed to program files(x86). But when I go to plot my model in keras, I still get the error saying I have to install pydot and graphviz and that the import failed. I can do

```
    import pydot
    import graphviz
```

on my python console just fine, they throw no errors. What else should I do to be able to graph my neural net?

Comment: Try: `py -m pip3 install pydot
    py -m pip3 install graphviz`

Comment: I don't have pip3. But usually if I just use "py -m pip" that's already for python 3 cus to get to python 2 I have to do py -2.7 -m pip install...etc. Also, I tested the import statements with python 3 and it works.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The path(s) to the installed GraphViz executables (`dot`, `neato`, etc.) need to be in the [`PATH` environment variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)), in order for `pydot` to find them. `pydot` used to search for those executables in earlier versions, but [not any more](https://github.com/erocarrera/pydot/issues/109).

Also:

1. [`pydot`](https://github.com/erocarrera/pydot) is a Python package.
2. [GraphViz](http://www.graphviz.org/) is a collection of tools [written in C](https://github.com/ellson/MOTHBALLED-graphviz) for computing graph layouts
3. [`graphviz`](https://github.com/xflr6/graphviz) is a Python package entirely unrelated to `pydot`. These two Python packages do not interact in any way with each other. Installing one of them should suffice (together with GraphViz).

See also:

- https://github.com/erocarrera/pydot/issues/126
- https://github.com/erocarrera/pydot/commit/812e3c40dac1e0225391481073c64da5bafba93e#commitcomment-18236709
- https://github.com/erocarrera/pydot/commit/812e3c40dac1e0225391481073c64da5bafba93e#commitcomment-18222580

and links from there.

Comment: So does that mean I have to go into the source code of pydot and manually add the path to graphviz?

Comment: I figured it out, sorry, I've never made edits to my windows PATH variable before.

Comment: In case that the user calls `pydot` directly (not via `keras` or other intermediary), then a middle solution is to pass the path via the `prog` argument of the `Dot.write_*` or `Dot.create_*` methods (see [this docstring](https://github.com/erocarrera/pydot/blob/35a8d858bd9da0b37268fe9b317fe4895387e75f/pydot.py#L1834)). However, this solution is discouraged. Better to set an environment configuration, and copy it when reinstalling the OS. In *nix systems this is usually done in `~/.bashrc` (I recommend committing this configuration file to a `git` repository).

Comment: Have a look over this answer with complete procedure -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/50025414/6126603

Comment: @dataLeo `keras >= 2.1.6` has been updated to recent versions of `pydot`: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/pull/9904

Comment: @loannis Thanks for the response. My answer targeted keras version 2.1.5

Answer (score 2):

Complementing @Ioannis answer, you have to install GraphViz executables via conda (`conda install GraphViz`).

For my case, after installing GraphViz I tried with the latest pydot (`pip install pydot`) and the error was resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Just to complete the @dataLeo 's solution, Python 3 users can use pydotplus package instead of pydot-ng package. To summarize:

1. install pydot+graphviz and pydotplus by commands "conda install pydot" and "conda install -c conda-forge pydotplus".
2. Go to the vis_utils.py file and change line 11 from `import pydot` to 
   `import pydotplus as pydot`.

PS: You can locate the vis_utils.py file by checking help for plot_model command in ipython console, i.e. after `from keras.utils import plot_model`, type `??plot_model` in ipython console.

Tested on Windows 10-64 bit with Anaconda python-3.6

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by installing the packages with :

```
conda install graphviz
conda install pydot
conda install pydotplus
```