# python - theano printing pydotprint - runtime error: failed to import pydot

Tags: python, anaconda, theano, pydot

I am trying to run this script https://github.com/dennybritz/nn-theano/blob/master/nn-theano.ipynb which implements a neural network using theano.

All goes fine until I get to the cell:

```
theano.printing.pydotprint(forward_prop, var_with_name_simple=True, compact=True, outfile='img/nn-theano-forward_prop.png', format='png')
SVG(theano.printing.pydotprint(forward_prop, var_with_name_simple=True, compact=True, return_image=True, format='svg'))
```

Then I get this error:

> ```
> RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
> <ipython-input-11-db44e43f05ee> in <module>()
> ----> 1 theano.printing.pydotprint(forward_prop, var_with_name_simple=True, compact=True, outfile='img/nn-theano-forward_prop.png', format='png')
>       2 SVG(theano.printing.pydotprint(forward_prop, var_with_name_simple=True, compact=True, return_image=True, format='svg'))
> ```
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\printing.py in pydotprint(fct, outfile, compact, format, with_ids, high_contrast, cond_highlight, colorCodes, max_label_size, scan_graphs, var_with_name_simple, print_output_file, return_image)
>       781                            " and either pydot or pydot-ng for "
>       782                            "`pydotprint` to work.",
>   --> 783                            pydot_imported_msg)
>       784 
>       785     g = pd.Dot()
>
> ```
> RuntimeError: ('Failed to import pydot. You must install graphviz and either pydot or pydot-ng for `pydotprint` to work.', 'An error happened while importing/trying pydot: (2, \'"dot.exe" not found in path.\', None, 2, None)')
> ```

I have read other questions on Stack and have tried installing graphviz via https://graphviz.gitlab.io/

I have pydot, pydotplus, graphviz (2.38.0) and also python-graphviz (0.8.2) installed. 
I am using Anaconda Navigator which I have recently updated.
Python 3.6.4
Windows 10 32bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GraphViz executables need to be in the `$PATH` variable for `pydot` to find them. Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47209738/1959808

`pydotplus` is an unmaintained fork of `pydot`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is GraphViz different to graphviz? How do i find out exactly what needs to be added to the $PATH variable?

Comment: [GraphViz](https://www.graphviz.org/) plots graphs. I use capitalization to emphasize that there is no executable named [`graphviz`, and also to avoid confusion with the Python package `graphviz`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/graphviz), which is *another* interface to GraphViz (i.e., its purpose is similar to `pydot`). The executables of GraphViz that Theano calls need to be in the path. This is probably `dot`, but all of them are installed in the same directory, so adding that directory to the path would suffice.

Comment: Thank you for your help again. To be clear, I need to add the directory that holds GraphViz to the path?

Comment: The directory that contains `dot`, `neato`, and the other executables.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is giving the clue here: `dot.exe` is missing in the path (`C:/Anaconda/Library/bin`). Complementing @Ioannis answer, you have to install GraphViz executables (via conda) for getting the `dot.exe` in your path.

For my case, after installing GraphViz (`conda install GraphViz`) I tried with the latest pydot (`pip install pydot`) and the error was resolved.