# error when trying to use keras.utils.plot_model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to make a plot/graph of deep learning model in Python using Keras package but unfortunately it keeps giving me an error which is not very informative.

I run python on Linux with Python 3.5.2, Anaconda 4.2.0, Keras 2.1.6 and I use tensorflow-gpu 1.7.0 Backend.

Here is the error message:

```
keras.utils.plot_model(unet, to_file='model.png', show_shapes=False, show_layer_names=True, rankdir='TB')

['dot', '-Tps', '/tmp/tmphesl1j0c'] return code: 127

stdout, stderr:
 b''
b'dot: error while loading shared libraries: libexpat.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory\n'

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-60bb0e3b97bd> in <module>()
----> 1 keras.utils.plot_model(unet, to_file='model.png', show_shapes=False, show_layer_names=True, rankdir='TB')

/.../anaconda3-4.2.0/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/utils/vis_utils.py in plot_model(model, to_file, show_shapes, show_layer_names, rankdir)
    132             'LR' creates a horizontal plot.
    133     """
--> 134     dot = model_to_dot(model, show_shapes, show_layer_names, rankdir)
    135     _, extension = os.path.splitext(to_file)
    136     if not extension:

/.../anaconda3-4.2.0/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/utils/vis_utils.py in model_to_dot(model, show_shapes, show_layer_names, rankdir)
     53     from ..models import Sequential
     54 
---> 55     _check_pydot()
     56     dot = pydot.Dot()
     57     dot.set('rankdir', rankdir)

/.../anaconda3-4.2.0/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/utils/vis_utils.py in _check_pydot()
     24         # Attempt to create an image of a blank graph
     25         # to check the pydot/graphviz installation.
---> 26         pydot.Dot.create(pydot.Dot())
     27     except OSError:
     28         raise OSError(

/.../anaconda3-4.2.0/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pydot.py in create(self, prog, format, encoding)
   1882                      out=stdout_data,
   1883                      err=stderr_data))
-> 1884         assert p.returncode == 0, p.returncode
   1885         return stdout_data

AssertionError: 127
```

I would really appreciate if somebody could help me with this error.

Note: both pydot and graphviz are intalled

Comment: have u got the answer as I'm having same problem ?

Comment: @AshishSaini yes it was some compatibility issue. I can't recall exactly what it was right now. But try some of the suggestions from this thread

Answer (score 7):

For me solution was to import like this:

```py
from keras.utils.vis_utils import plot_model
```

Comment: Thank you! I am surprised that this was answered just 19 hours before I faced the problem. You saved my day!

Comment: It doesn't work for me. `AttributeError: module 'keras.api._v2.keras.utils' has no attribute 'vis_utils'` I use `from tensorflow.keras.utils import plot_model` instead.

Answer (score 6):

For me the solution was:

- `conda install pydotplus` (pydot-ng was not installable with tensorflow-gpu it said).
- Search for viz_utils.py in anaconda directory and open all of them. Make sure everywhere pydot is imported, it is done the following way:

```
try:
  # pydot-ng is a fork of pydot that is better maintained.
  import pydot_ng as pydot
except ImportError:
  # pydotplus is an improved version of pydot
  try:
    import pydotplus as pydot
  except ImportError:
    # Fall back on pydot if necessary.
    try:
      import pydot
    except ImportError:
      pydot = None
```

There was one of the files where it just said `import pyplot`. After changing that, it worked for me.

Answer (score 6):

I changed keras.utils to tensorflow.keras.utils and it helped me

Comment: and is now: tensorflow.python.keras.utils

Answer (score 1):

It seems like that there are some compatibility issue ! ([Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47209738/1454173))

Installing [Graphviz](https://www.graphviz.org/) and adding it to [paths](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)) works for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running an IDE like PyCharm, after installing pydot and installing Graphviz(also adding it to the environment **PATH variable**. eg C:\Program Files\Graphviz\bin. see here https://www.architectryan.com/2018/03/17/add-to-the-path-on-windows-10/), you should **restart the IDE**.

If you are working in a virtual environment, I would suggest deactivate and restart the terminal and activate the virtual environment again.

**Reason** - the package is trying to locate graphviz from os.environ['PATH'], and somehow it was not updated to show graphviz in the path.
After restarting Pycharm, I found os.environ['PATH'] was properly updated and the plot_model function worked correctly.

Answer (score 1):

For me, there was an error where I didn't put '' over model.png in.

plot_model(model, to_file= 'model.png' , show_shapes=True)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue commenting line 117 `program += extension` in `pydot.py`

Answer (score 0):

```
from keras.utils.vis_utils import plot_model
keras.utils.vis_utils.plot_model(
csf1, to_file='model.png', show_shapes=True, show_dtype=True,
show_layer_names=True, rankdir='TB', expand_nested=True, dpi=96
)
```

You can use this code, it works with my project correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The following code works for me:

```
conda install -c anaconda graphviz
conda install pydotplus
```

Just open your terminal and run the commands. Then you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Even I was facing this error since past 2 days.

I did the following:

```
conda uninstall pyplot
conda uninstall pyplotplus
conda uninstall graphviz
```

Then, I once again installed all these three packages.

```
conda install pyplot
conda install pyplotplus
conda install graphviz
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
import keras
keras.utils.plot_model(Your_Parameters)
```

or

```
from keras.utils import plot_model
plot_model(Your_Parameters)
```

Answer (score -1):

the comment says

```
 24         # Attempt to create an image of a blank graph
 25         # to check the pydot/graphviz installation.
```

so I suppose you need to install graphviz and pydot

assuming you are on ubuntu or similar:

```
sudo apt install graphviz
```

and in your anaconda env:

```
pip install pydot
```

Comment: Both pydot and graphviz  are installed

Comment: can you run `pydot.Dot.create(pydot.Dot())` in a python shell? I did the above 2 and it works for me, I am not using anaconda though

Comment: I am not use but I think there is a mistake with (). I tried different combinations of () but every time it says `Badly placed ()'s`

Comment: idk, I did exactly the above (apt, pip, and the python line) and it works, both with python 2.7 and 3.5